# Express dosent take file even if i use fileUpload but Postman does

Tags: reactjs, express

i need to send file (image) with req.body data for express. And upload that image later. I use app.use(fileUpload()); instead of multer because its too difucult to understand how it works.

My axios looks like:

```
let form = new FormData();

    form.append('pfp', pfp);
    form.append("login", login);
    form.append('password', password);
    form.append("role", role);

    const { data } = await $auth_host.post('/api/user/registrateByAdmin', { form }, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    });
```

It doesnt work. Express in req.headers sees 'content-type'
I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: try change { form } to form

Comment: thanks.... thanks a lot, it helped. I spent the whole day. If you don't mind, can you tell me why it works now. i'm a little confused

Comment: A few months ago I also had the same problem. My assumption is that formData is already a data object, so there is no need to add { }. please upvote my previous comment if you don't mind :)

Comment: how can i do it, there is only flag no arrows or somthing looks like vote button. I am   new user, sorry for dump question :D

Comment: Then in my answer below :D, thanks mate

Comment: "
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let form = new FormData();

    form.append('pfp', pfp);
    form.append("login", login);
    form.append('password', password);
    form.append("role", role);

    const { data } = await $auth_host.post('/api/user/registrateByAdmin', form , {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    });
```

Try changing { form } to form